# Evaluate integral using transformation multi

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> $$\int_{D} \int \frac{y}{x} dA$$ where $D$ is the region in the 1st (top right) quadrant bounded by $y = 0, y = x, x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$. Disregard the $(0, 0)$ issue for now. Mapping transform $D$

Can you provide an idea as to how I can transform the integral? I am not sure which mapping to use.

Comment: what is $A$ in $dA$?

Comment: you can take $x=2r\cos\theta , y=r\sin \theta$, then $0\leq r\leq 1$, $0\leq \theta\leq \arctan (2)$ (my calculation may be wrong!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying the substitution $u=\frac yx$ and $v=x^2+4y^2$. Solving for $x$ and $y$ yields $x=\sqrt{\frac{v}{1+4u^2}}$ and $y=u\sqrt{\frac{v}{1+4u^2}}$. With a little effort, $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=-\frac{1}{8u^2+2}$ and this problem reduces to integrating $f(u,v)=\frac{u}{8u^2+2}$ over the rectangular subset of the $(u,v)$ plane $[0,1]\times[0,4].$ You get $\frac{\ln(5)}{4}.$

Comment: How did you solve for $x$?

Comment: $y=ux \iff v=x^2+4(ux)^2 \iff v=x^2(1+4u^2) \iff x^2=\frac{v}{1+4u^2}$. Take a square root to get $x.$ No need for a plus or minus since $x$ is in the first quadrant.

Comment: How do you get $v= 0$ as the bottom boundary?

Comment: Look at the image of $D$ under $T(x,y)=(u,v).$ I suggest graphing the IMAGE of the three curves on the boundary of $D$ in the $(u,v)$ plane. You could also express the region $D$ as a union of sets $\big\{{y=\sqrt{\frac{C-x^2}{4}}|{\sqrt{\frac{C}{5}}}}\leq{x}\leq{\sqrt{C}\big\}}$ over $0<{C}\leq{4}$ to minimize the calculation when computing this image.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\iint_{D}{y \over x}\,\dd x\,\dd y & =
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}\bracks{y > 0}\bracks{y < x}
\bracks{x^{2} + 4y^{2} < 4}{y \over x}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}\bracks{y > 0}\bracks{{y \over 2} < x}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} < 4}{y \over 2x}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{r\sin\pars{\theta} > 0}
\bracks{{r\sin\pars{\theta} \over 2} < r\cos\pars{\theta}}
{r\sin\pars{\theta} \over 2\bracks{r\cos\pars{\theta}}}\,r\,\dd r\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\bracks{\sin\pars{\theta} > 0}
\bracks{\cot\pars{\theta} > {1 \over 2}}\tan\pars{\theta}\,r\,\dd r\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}
\bracks{\cot\pars{\theta} > {1 \over 2}}\tan\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
\bracks{-\tan\pars{\theta} > {1 \over 2}}\bracks{-\cot\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\braces{\bracks{\tan\pars{\theta} < -\,{1 \over 2}} -
\bracks{\tan\pars{\theta} > {1 \over 2}}}
\cot\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{\arctan\pars{1/2}}^{\pi/2}\cot\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta =
\left.{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\theta}}
\right\vert_{\ \arctan\pars{1/2}}^{\ \pi/2}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{\arctan\pars{1 \over 2}}} =
\bbx{{1 \over 4}\ln\pars{5}} \approx 0.4024
\end{align}